# Using Local Variable Value As Query Criteria SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Background: I want to compare each column in all tables for two Person records by looping through all possible columns. I then want to run a common table expression which uses each column as it loops, and if the second Person column is NULL, I want it to update with the value of the first Person column, for all duplicate records based on specific criteria.

This will essentially loop through all duplicates and update them to match, prior to deleting one.

I am running a stored procedure which loops through table columns. I would like to use those columns in a query. Here is what I have:

```
declare table_columns cursor local dynamic for
     select BaseTable,
            DBColumn
     from viewTableInfo


declare @BaseTable nvarchar (100)
declare @DBColumn nvarchar (100)
open table_columns

while (1 = 1)
      begin
           fetch next from table_columns into @BaseTable, @DBColumn
                 if (@@FETCH_STATUS <> 0 ) break

                 ;with CTE as
                 (
                  select firstName,
                         lastName,
                         @DBColumn AS Column,
                         rn = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY firstName, lastName ORDER BY pID)
                  from Person p
                  inner join Company c ON c.pID = p.pID -- joined because variable may be column from Company table.
                  where p.pID in (1, 2)
                  )
                  select destinationProperty = case
                                               when c1.Column = c2.Column then c2.Column
                                               when c2.Column IS NULL THEN c1.Column
                                               ELSE c2.Column END
                  from cte c1
                  inner join cte c2 on c1.firstName = c2.firstName and c1.lastName = c2.LastName and c2.rn = c1.rn + 1
```

When I run this, I get zero records in the result set because the common table expression is selecting the value of the variable @DBColumn, which, for each loop, is the actual Column Name.

What I need is to be able to use the actual Column name in the query and get the value of that column for each pID in the result set.

Is this possible?

Comment: you need to write dynamic sql and use exec

Comment: Be careful here...why are you using while 1 = 1? For that matter why are you using a loop at all? I don't fully understand what you are trying to do but from what you posted I don't see the need for a loop at all.

Comment: @SeanLange My cursor selects all available columns from a specific table which both records have. The values among those columns will differ between both records. I want to loop through each column and set them equal to each other when one of them is NULL.

Comment: @RADAR I found an example of dynamic SQL, however I do not think I can use that inside my CTE and still reference the column variable.

Comment: That didn't really explain it very clearly but there really is no need for a loop here. This sounds like a single update from statement.

Comment: @SeanLange I have another stored procedure which finds duplicate records across the system based on matching criteria. It then groups those records and sends pIDs into this loop. Then it takes both of those records and calls another stored procedure which takes care of other referential data, then finally deletes one of the duplicates. I need to loop because I also get the data type for each column, and call certain functions depending on dates,int,bits, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure of exact requirement to use cursor and dynamic column names here, but you can get the required functionality using dynamic SQL.

Changed the loop not to use 1=1 , instead to check for cursor status.

```
declare table_columns cursor local dynamic for
     select BaseTable,
            DBColumn
     from viewTableInfo


declare @BaseTable nvarchar (100)
declare @DBColumn nvarchar (100)

declare @query nvarchar(max)

open table_columns
fetch next from table_columns into @BaseTable, @DBColumn

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin

    set @query =';with CTE as
                 (
                  select firstName,
                         lastName,
                         ' + @DBColumn + ' AS Column,
                         rn = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY firstName, lastName ORDER BY pID)
                  from Person p
                  inner join Company c ON c.pID = p.pID -- joined because variable may be column from Company table.
                  where p.pID in (1, 2)
                  )
                  select destinationProperty = case
                                               when c1.Column = c2.Column then c2.Column
                                               when c2.Column IS NULL THEN c1.Column
                                               ELSE c2.Column END
                  from cte c1
                  inner join cte c2 on c1.firstName = c2.firstName and c1.lastName = c2.LastName and c2.rn = c1.rn + 1'

    exec sp_executesql @query
fetch next from table_columns into @BaseTable, @DBColumn
end
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it works how I need it to. I wish I could clarify better, there's a lot to it. Your answer totally worked though. Thanks again.